# How to prevent multiple confirmation dialogue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a button which when clicked, displays a calendar for the user to change the date of an item. After the date is chosen, there will be a confirmation dialogue to ensure that the user would like to proceed. The problem that my code is currently facing is that when the calendar is displayed and the user let's say click the background, the calendar disappear. When the user clicks the button again and proceed to choose the date, the confirmation dialogue comes out multiple times, probably because of the previous attempts. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```js
function reschedule(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#change").datetimepicker({
      "format" : "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss",
      "autoclose" : true,
      "startDate" : new Date(),
      pickerPosition: 'bottom left'
    }).on('changeDate', function (input) {
      if ( confirm("Move to " + new Date(input.date).toISOString() + "?") ) {
        // code to change date
      }
    });
    $("#change").datetimepicker("show");
}
```

Comment: When user clicks on background, you have to create a function which press No on the confirmation dialog. In this way, multiple dialog box wont pop up.

Comment: Which datetimepicker plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are calling the `reschedule()` function each time the user clicks your button, which causes the same "changeDate" event to be attached multiples times on the element.

To prevent that, you can try moving the code that initializes the date-time-picker outside the `reschedule()` function.

See the code below.

```
$("#change").datetimepicker({
  "format" : "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss",
  "autoclose" : true,
  "startDate" : new Date(),
  pickerPosition: 'bottom left'
}).on('changeDate', function (input) {
  if ( confirm("Move to " + new Date(input.date).toISOString() + "?") ) {
    // code to change date
  }
});

function reschedule(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#change").datetimepicker("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the solution, just have to unbind it when the calendar is hidden.

```js
function reschedule(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#change").datetimepicker({
      "format" : "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss",
      "autoclose" : true,
      "startDate" : new Date(),
      pickerPosition: 'bottom left'
    }).on('changeDate', function (input) {
      if ( confirm("Move to " + new Date(input.date).toISOString() + "?") ) {
        // code to change date
      }
    }).on('hide', function () {
        $("#change").unbind();
    });
    $("#change").datetimepicker("show");
}
```